# Error: missing revert data in call exception on tokenOfOwnerByIndex and tokenByIndex from openzeppelin ERC721Enumerable

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts

I'm getting a odd error across several calls out to openzeppelin that

> Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string

I didn't change anything and am using out of the box openzeppelin and minimal test harness code

```
contract MyToken is ERC721Enumerable
```

This works fine and I successfully call several internal functions from my tests like

```
const totalSupply = await myTokenContract.totalSupply();
const ownerBalance = await myTokenContract.balanceOf(owner.address);
```

these both work just fine

However, when calling functions like `tokenOfOwnerByIndex` or `tokenByIndex` I get that Error

```
const ownerToken = await myTokenContract.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(
  owner.address, ethers.BigNumber.from(1).toNumber()
);

const ownerToken = await myTokenContract.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(
  owner.address, 1
);

const firstToken = await myTokenContract.tokenByIndex(1);
```

These each produce the same error that

> Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string

I'm assuming it's some environmental configuration issue but I can't quite seem to figure it out?

hardhat 2.9.3, openzeppelin/contracts 4.6.0, solidity 0.8.1